# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"- while creating pivot in Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm trying to create a pivot table by opening an Excel file from my drive.

But I'm receiving the error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I have attached my code below

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim excelApplication As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = Nothing
        Dim excelWorkBook As Workbook = Nothing
        Dim targetSheet As Worksheet = Nothing
        Dim pivotTable As PivotTable = Nothing
        Dim pivotData As Ranges = Nothing
        Dim pivotDestination As Range = Nothing
        Dim co As PivotField = Nothing
        Dim pivotTableName As String = "Complexity"
        excelApplication.Workbooks.Open("E:\John\ccc.xlsx")
        pivotData = targetSheet.Range("Data!R1C1:R11460C9")
        pivotDestination = targetSheet.Range("Data!R1C11")
        excelWorkBook.PivotTableWizard( _
            XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, _
            pivotData, pivotDestination, pivotTableName, True, True, _
           True, True, , , False, False, XlOrder.xlDownThenOver, 0)
        With excelApplication.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Complexity").PivotFields("Com")
        End With
        excelApplication.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Complexity").AddDataField(excelApplication.ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
            "Complexity").PivotFields("Per gram"), "Sum of Per gram", XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum)
        excelApplication.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Complexity").AddDataField(excelApplication.ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
            "Complexity").PivotFields("Oracle Per gram"), "Sum of Oracle Per gram", XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum)
        excelApplication.ActiveWorkbook.Close()
        excelApplication.Quit()
    End Sub
```

Comment: what line do you get the error on? open the code, press F9 on the start line of code, press F8 to step through the code until you get the error. My guess is that the range `Data!R1C1:R11460C9` is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

`Dim excelApplication As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = Nothing` ,`excelApplication` is `Nothing` ...

try this:

```
excelApplication = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`
excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open("E:\John\ccc.xlsx")
targetSheet = excelWorkBook.Sheets(0) 
' assuming that the sheet you want to work with is the first one.
```